# Events in succesion with increased probability

Tags: probability

A student is practicing for an exam and believes he has a 0.7 chance of passing. If he fails, he will train more and try again. He believes that training more will increase the probability of being passed by 10% for each attempt. Assuming his predictions are correct, on which attempt is he guaranteed to pass? What is the probability of needing more than 2 tests?

My first take on this problem was P(A_2)=1.1*P(A_1) where A_i represents the iteration of taking the test but after 4 iteration probability goes beyond 1 wich doesn't makes sense to me. Another take on this i tried was using bayes rules but i dont know if i can consider A_2 and ~A_1 as independent from each other. The problem doesn't explain what it means by "increases by 10%" it just states that. It is a bit too much ambigous to me and i dont find a satisfying answer

Comment: It is tempting, but I think wrong to conclude that the 2nd attempt will have a probability of success of $(0.7) + [ ~0.1 \times (1 - 0.7) ~] = 0.73,~$ for two reasons: for one thing, this sort of interpretation is a rather convoluted interpretation of the phrase "...increase the probability of being passed by 10%...".  For another, you are faced with the unusual question: "on which attempt is he guaranteed to pass?", which would be inconsistent with the convoluted interpretation.  ...see next comment

Comment: So, I think that the probability of success on attempt $~k~$ is $~(0.7) \times (1.1)^{k-1},~$ until this expression exceeds $1.0.$  So, on attempt-2, the probability of success is $~0.77.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret the 10% as an arithmetic progression of 10%, ie $0.7, 0.8,0.9,1.0$, as a multiplicative increase seems unrealistic to me. If I were to model a study-result curve, it would be one with declining slope, at best linear.

P(pass on first trial) $= 0.7$

P(fail on first, succeed on second) $=0.3*0.8 = 0.24$

This P(pass in at most 2 trials) $=0.7+0.24$, and so on.

Can you proceed now ?

Comment: +1 : Creative alternative interpretation.  Unclear to me whether your interpretation represents the problem composer's intent.  However, you justified your interpretation nicely, and (also) demonstrated that your interpretation keeps the posted question (i.e. probability of needing more than 2 tries) **non-trivial**.

Comment: @user2661923: Yea, a pity that creativity has to be employed in interpreting underspecified problems, rather than in solving them...

Comment: thank you that seems a very good interpretation, i hate this kind of ambigous questions. Especially in math

Comment: @KralTar: You are welcome !$\;\;$ :)